# How to find and update the latest record in mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My mongodb contains duplicate records and I want to update the latest record. So Im trying the sort criteria as follows.

```
modelname.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {$set: options },async function(err,result){
  if(err)
     next(err)
  else{
   console.log("updated");
  }
  }).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Here I'am trying to sort using the createdAt but I'am unable to update the latest record. Please help me where I'am going wrong.

If I try to print the result.

```
  result ------- :  { _id: 5e047b81115fcff2d7f55507,
                      BatchId: '1577352062756',
                      ServiceCode: '1',
                      PhoneNumber: '7777777775',
                      Preset: '3',
                      Otype: 'A',
                      PType: '2',
                      Status: 'Success',
                      __v: 0,
                     createdAt: 2019-12-26T09:21:05.372Z,
                     updatedAt: 2019-12-26T10:23:28.199Z }
```

Comment: Try logging the error using console.log(err) and post that error here.

Comment: Please share full code  ?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Im not getting any error. If I try to print the result, Im getting the latest record. But it is not updated..

Comment: you are getting previous record ??

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar No Im getting the latest record only. But in db its not getting updated..

Comment: Please tell  value of the key  filter, {$set: options }  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **new** keyword with **true** value then we get updated record.

```
modelname.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {$set: options }, { new: true },async function(err,result){
      if(err)
         next(err)
      else{
       console.log("updated");
      }
      }).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Answer (score 1):

method `findOneAndUpdate` will by default return old version of document, and when you provide option `{ new: true }`, it will return you new, updated version of object